# Dynamic DLL usage in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

I've searched on google and here quite a lot for my problem and can't seem to find a solution.

I have this huge solution, one of the projects(let's call it "Main") have reference to two other projects(A and B). Projects A and B have a reference dll from an external tool, it's the same tool, but different versions of it. The developer must have the tool installed in the computer to be able to use it.

Now, Project A uses Tool_v1.dll, and Project B uses Tool_v2.dll. If a developer has Tool_v2 installed, they can build the Main project with no problems, but if he has Tool_v1, the old version, he can't build Project B for obvious reasons.

My idea to solve this(as a developer with old Tool_v1 installed) was to make two build configurations in VS, but just having the Project B's referenced, even if not used, still causes it to be built, thus giving errors when I want to build the solution.

If I simply delete Project B's reference works like a charm, but I wanted to simply choose the build configuration it's and done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two different configurations, each with specific reference lists/locations.

I have detailed instructions on how to accomplish this here: https://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/configuration-specific-reference-location/[1](https://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/configuration-specific-reference-location/)